# Import old data into Trello?

Tags: trello, import

My company has been using a different project management service for years. Is there any way to bulk import data into Trello? Then, we could be off and running with what we have so far.

Comment: I'm preparing myself to get excited abut [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) but not all apis are open for users yet (eg Basecamp to Trello). One to watch though.

Comment: We wanted to do a similar thing, so we created a google spreadsheet to do the import. It's geared towards a scrum backlog, but you might be able to tweak it to your requirements. Details here http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/online-scrum-tools-part-3-upload-existing-product-backlog-into-trello/

Comment: This is a highly specific problem, for which there cannot be an internet service. But for an experienced programmer this will amount to not much more than a day of work, if you can pay a freelancer.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 10, 2023 there is an official help article [Importing data into Trello](https://support.atlassian.com/trello/docs/importing-data-into-trello/).

To access the Trello Help from the Trello web app UI, click the ? (question mark) button on the Trello toolbar. On narrow screens, this button might be hidden; in such cases, click the user profile photo to open the Account dropdown menu; this menu includes an option to extend the Trello Help.

According to this Import data into Trello help article, there is no generic import tool. The options are copy-paste, Trello API, and using Trello third-party power-ups.